# Java regex new search to include last group

Tags: java, regex

I want to get all substrings (`\d{2,3}`) so I use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)(\\D)(\\d{2,3})(\\D)");
```

For my example

```
strExample = " 123c12de34 ";
```

The match detects 2 matches: *123* and *34*.
Is there any pattern for detecting 3 matches: *123*, *12* and *34*?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:^|(?<=\D))(\d{2,3})(?=\D|$)
```

Instead of `match` use `0 width assertions` through `lookarounds`.This will enable all `3` as there will not be any `overlap` now

Comment: I try it withRegular Expression Test Page for Java

Comment: I try it with  Regular Expression Test Page for Java at regexplanet and I got first occurrence 12 for "123c12de34"  and 123 for " 123c12de34". I have to loop for each occurrence in substring?

Comment: What I want is to find all index in the original string where start an end my regex (\d{2,3}).

Comment: In general I want positions that starts and ends match a regex strings, which can have variable length strings.

Comment: @MToma `The match detects 2 matches: 123 and 34. Is there any pattern for detecting 3 matches: 123, 12 and 34?` this regex will find all `3` matches the same way it was matching only 2 before

Answer (score 0):

Use **positive-lookbehind** with alternation, by doing so, you'll be able to find numbers that are preceded by a start of the line or by a number:

**RegEx Pattern:** `/(?<=\A|\D)(\d+)/g`

[Working demo @ regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hO4cG4/1)

## Update #1

### Java Working Example

```
public class StackOverflow32336833 {
    public static String text;
    public static String pattern;

    static {
        text = "123c12de34";
        pattern = "(?<=\\A|\\D)(\\d+)";
    }

    public static void printMatches(String text, String pattern) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(text);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMatches(text, pattern);
    }   
}
```

Comment: How it is to be use in Java?

Comment: @MToma: You'll find a Java working example at the update on the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more question: I want (\d{2,3}) not (\d+); Can I do this?

Comment: @MToma: Sure, you just need to change the expression to: (?<=\\A|\\D)(\\d{2,3})